# Is it possible to define "characters in any sequence" in Regex?

Tags: regex

I want to match strings that start with 1-3 asterisks then two tildes (~) or the opposite order. So

```
~~**word**~~
```

Would match

As would

```
*~~word~~*
```

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using:

```
\*{1,3}~{2}|~{2}\*{1,3}
```

But if you want to capture the string `word` for those scenarios, then you could do:

```
\*{1,3}~{2}(\w+)~{2}\*{1,3}|~{2}\*{1,3}(\w+)\*{1,3}~{2}
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/eM0pJ1/1)**

[image]

Match information:

```
MATCH 1
2.  [4-8]   `word`
MATCH 2
1.  [17-21] `word`
```